# Loading only visible areas of a large image in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, image-loading

We're using cocos2d to display a large image which is comprised of three different parallaxing layers within an app for iPhone/iPad. The user will be able to pan around this large image.

These images will be approximately 13000 pixels wide, so we're concerned about memory usage.
Ideally we'd like to grid the image up and load subsections of it based on what is currently visible.

Does cocos2d include anything that will help us with this?
We've looked at using Tile maps (we have a prototype running on CCTMXTiledMap), but it doesn't seem like this is actually a good application of tile maps, as they're generally used for large maps/images that are comprised of repeated smaller images; whereas every tile in our large images will be unique.

Does anyone have any bright ideas about the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing a post on a blog where an iPhone programmer has images loading on a background thread as the screen scrolled.  He said so long as the scrolling isn't too fast, it's not a problem to achieve smooth scrolling.

You basically load the sections of the images based on where the screen is scrolling toward, and deallocate the images that leave the screen border.  So there would be the screen itself, and a border around the edges of the screen to act as a buffer in case the player goes back and forth (left or right, etc).

I wish I could find the link, but after searching for 30 minutes I gave up.  I did see his video and it scrolled very smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I implemented last night. We still get some jitteryness loading the textures in as you pan around; but I might be able to fix that by pre-cacheing textures, or putting in more of a buffer and loading them in the background.

Comment: Maybe divide the screen up into 9 or 12 rects, then place the buffer fully around the edges that match one rect in size.  As the player moves, load new buffers.  A good test would be to move diagonal then horizontal or vertical to test loading speeds.  I would test on multiple devices as the simulator definitely isn't a good platform for testing.